# Is it possible to use a member instead of let for an F# Event?

Tags: events, f#, observable

In this code, `EventL` uses a `let` binding and `EventM` (is an attempt to) use a member:

```
type MyType() =
   let EventL = new Event<_>()
   member this.EventM = new Event<_>()

   member this.AddHandlers() =
      Event.add (fun string1 -> printfn "EventL: %s" string1) EventL.Publish
      Event.add (fun string1 -> printfn "EventM: %s" string1) this.EventM.Publish

   member this.Trigger(message) =
      EventL.Trigger(message)
      this.EventM.Trigger(message)

let myMyType = MyType()
myMyType.AddHandlers()
myMyType.Trigger("Event arg.")
```

When run, this outputs only `EventL: Event arg.` while `EventM`'s handler is not called.

Am I making a silly mistake or missing some piece of logic regarding members?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `EventM` is a computed property that gets evaluated every time it's called. This results in different `Event` objects being created throughout the rest of your code (2 times, once in `AddHandlers`, next in `Trigger`).

Checkout the `member val` syntax. That creates a backing field and still gives public accessibility.

The fixed version would be:

```
type MyType() =
    member val EventM = new Event<_>()
```

If you don't have a primary constructor then you will need to use `val` instead and assign it in your constructor:

```
type MyType =
    val EventM : Event<string>
    new () = { EventM = new Event<_>() }
```

Note that in this case, you will have to give the type argument to `Event`.